# Call javascript during modalpopup.show()

Tags: javascript, button, panel, modalpopupextender

I have a javascript that disables a button for x seconds and then enables the button after x seconds pass.  An update button checks for certain constraints, and if met, a modal popup is shown.  The button the javascript is meant for is located in a panel displayed by this modal popup.  Is there a way I can execute the javascript when the modal popup / panel is shown?

Comment: What do you mean by when a "panel that is only popped up under certain conditions"? does it show as a popup or do you mean when it becomes visible? Help us, help you. Edit your question and post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach if you want to run JavaScript code when a modal popup is showing:

```
$find("myModalPopupExtender").add_showing(function() {
    alert("Modal popup will be shown.");
});
```

The `alert` will be shown each time the modal popup extender shows the popup.

Comment: This solution makes perfect sense, but for some reason it is not showing the alert.  "myModalPopupExtender" - is this the control's ID or the BehaviorID?

Comment: After adding a BehaviorID to the popupextender and moving this script to the pageLoad() function in the .aspx page I was able to get this to work.  Thank you for the help!